# Define custom constant lookup with const_missing in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have to test some base classes that provide a lot of meta programmed tooling in Ruby 3.2. The tricky part is, that it creates methods and tooling based on the constant name of another class. This is fine in production and development, as Zeitwerk loads all the dependencies automatically: When `MyBaseTooling` is missing, it looks in a file called `my_base_tooling.rb` and loads the class for me.

In RSpec however, I have to take care of it myself using `stub_const`:

```
before do
  stub_const(MyBaseTooling, Class.new(Tooling::Base))
  stub_const(MyClass, Class.new(described_class) do
    setup(MyBaseTooling) # parses the name "MyBaseTooling" and does some logic based on the name
  end)
end
```

This get's pretty messy pretty fast, when you have some context blocks and you overwrite definitions in deeper blocks:

```
describe do
  let(:my_base_tooling) do
    stub_const(MyBaseTooling, Class.new(Tooling::Base))
  end
  let(:my_class) do
    my_base_tooling # preload the constant
    stub_const(MyClass, Class.new(described_class) do
      setup(MyBaseTooling) # parses the name "MyBaseTooling" and does some logic based on the name
    end)
  end

  context "with more logic in my base tooling" do
    let(:my_base_tooling) do
      stub_const(MyBaseTooling, Class.new(Tooling::Base) do
        # more custom logic
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

The part I don't like is the manual load of `MyBaseTooling` by calling the let of `my_base_tooling` inside the `let(:my_class)`. Imagine you don't have just 2 classes, you have 8 or more of them (this is my current case).

So I thought, maybe I could provide a custom lookup logic for RSpec, when a constant is missing just like Zeitwerk does. But instead of looking for files, I would look for let helpers with the same naming convention. My ideas so far are:

- Somehow using `const_missing` ([https://devdocs.io/ruby~3.2/module#method-i-const_missing](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3.2/module#method-i-const_missing))
- When a constant is missing doing a `name.underscore` and look if a let is defined with this name; if so, return this value

I played around with the `const_missing` hook, but haven't got any luck so far. Any ideas how to do this, or if this is even possible?

Comment: I've removed my answer as you clearly did not find it helpful. Perhaps if your question were more clear, you would actually get an answer that you find helpful.

Comment: *In RSpec however, I have to take care of it myself* What? Why? Zeitwerk works fine in test environments. How are you loading your application in test that bypasses Zeitwerk? More importantly, why would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution using a stub for `Object#const_missing`:

```
# spec/helpers/stub_const_lazy.rb
module StubConstLazy
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    prepend_before do
      if self.class.stubbed_consts.any?
        allow(Object).to receive(:const_missing).and_wrap_original do |callback, const|
          instance_exec(&self.class.stubbed_consts.fetch(const) { callback.call(const) })
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class_methods do
    def stubbed_consts
      parent_groups.map(&:stubbed_const_definitions).reverse.inject(&:merge)
    end

    def stubbed_const_definitions
      @stubbed_const_definitions ||= {}
    end

    def stub_class(name, parent = nil, &)
      stubbed_const_definitions[name.to_sym] = -> {
        arg = parent.is_a?(String) ? parent.constantize : parent || Class.new
        stub_class(name, arg, &)
      }
    end

    def stub_const(name, value = nil)
      stubbed_const_definitions[name.to_sym] = -> { stub_const(name.to_s, value || yield) }
    end
  end
end
```

Include it in your `spec_helper.rb` like this:

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include StubConstLazy
  # ...
end
```

Now you can stub classes and constants like this in a spec and you never have to worry about loading orders any more (e.g. you can overwrite previously defined classes and consts in describe or context blocks):

```
describe "some specs" do
  describe "#stub_const" do
    stub_const("FOO", "foo")

    it "returns foo" do
      expect(FOO).to eq("foo")
    end

    describe "when overwritten" do
      stub_const("FOO", "bar")

      it "returns bar" do
        expect(FOO).to eq("bar")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#stub_class" do
    stub_class("LazyDefined", Object)

    stub_class("MyClass", "LazyDefined") do
      def foo
        "foo"
      end
    end

    it "returns bar" do
      expect(MyClass.new.foo).to eq("foo")
    end

    context "when overwriting stub_class" do
      stub_class("MyClass", Object) do
        def foo
          "bar"
        end
      end

      it "returns bar" do
        expect(MyClass.new.foo).to eq("bar")
      end
    end
  end
end
```